# Events on dynamically added classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

I have a form where the class of the button is dynamically changing, depending up where the request is coming from. I am trying to capture the onclick event, but it does not take in the dynamically added class. I made sure that the class is being added to the button. Where can I be going wrong.

Snippets --

```
   $('.button').removeClass('oldClass');
   $('.button').addClass('newClass');

   <button class = "button">Button</button>
```

OnClick --

```
     $('.newClass').click(function(){
          alert("test");
     });
```

The code does not get to this event event though the button class is changed to newClass.

Thanks

Comment: You select elements, and bind a handler to the matched elements. If the elements don't have that class at the time of the selection, they won't be selected, and therefore they won't get the handler bound.

Comment: JQuery applies the click functionality when the DOM object loads (when you first refresh a page). Since the button does not have the new class at this time, it never gets the click function set to it.

Comment: In the example I am binding the event to the newClass name..

Comment: @Fox: I'll say it again. You're selecting elements based on the class. If the element(s) don't have that class at the time of the selection, they won't be selected, and so they won't have a handler bound to them.

Comment: how are you adding the elements dinamycally?

Answer (score 3):

Thats cause when you bind the click event the element has another class.

Try somesthing like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.newClass', function () {
        alert('test');
    });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BWUje/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Setting event handlers through methods like [.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (or shortcuts like .click) are only set for elements that currently match the selector. If you want to set up the event handler for elements that currently match as well as all future matches then you should use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the click functionality directly to the button when the DOM loads, and just use `.hasClass()` to check if the newClass has been applied or not.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('newClass')) {
        //Code for new class click
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yRySK/1/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using the delegate method provided by JQuery.

```
$('body').delegate('.newClass','click', delegatefunction);

function hasClass() {
   alert("Hello!!");
}
```

Thanks for the help.